# Relax visual-studio C compiler syntax for

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible under VS 2008 C/C++ compiler, compiling the following code in/as a .c file ?

```
int f(int bounds)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < bounds ; i++ )
   { .... } 
   return sum;
}
```

GCC seem to be ok with that C syntax, but it looks like VS'2008 is more expecting something like:

```
int f(int bounds)
{
   int sum = 0, i;
   for( i = 0; i < bounds ; i++ )
   { .... } 
   return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible under VS 2008 C/C++ compiler, compiling the following code in/as a .c file ?

No. This is a C99 feature and MSVC doesn't support C99. You must have to declare `i` before `for` loop.